# How to use TestNG with Selenium IDE?

Tags: testing, testng, selenium-ide

Is it possible to use TestNG with selenium IDE to created data driven script. If possible could you please provide me any reference link or procedure for it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can done by using [**Selenium Client Drivers (Java)**](http://seleniumhq.org/download/#client-drivers) (but not Selenium IDE).

See **[Selenium and TestNG](http://file:///D:/Eclipse%20Project%20Library/TestNG/testng-6.2/doc/selenium.html)**.

For Maven

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
    <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
    <version>6.3</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
  <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
  <version>2.11.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium.client-drivers</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java-client-driver</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```